# How to view raw HTTP request and raw HTTP response, using node-rest-client

Tags: node.js, rest, http

Is there a way to view the complete raw HTTP request and response to make debugging easier?
Here is the node module ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client ) and an example.

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
client = new Client();

args = {
     path:{"p1":"1234", "p2":"abcd"}
     headers:{"Authorization":"01234567890"}
}

client.get("http://example.com/${p1}/${p2}", args, function(data, response){
            // parsed response body as js object 
            console.log(data);
            // raw response 
            console.log(response);
        }).on('error',function(err){
            console.log('something went wrong on the request', err.request.options);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [source code](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client/blob/master/lib/node-rest-client.js), the [`Client.get()`](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client/blob/master/lib/node-rest-client.js#L284) function returns a regular ol' request object created (eventually, under the hood) by node's `http` or `https` module.  So try examining the return value of `client.get()` and seeing what's inside.